# data type mismatch criteria expression in vb.net,access while inserting

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class insuranceform
    Dim read As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Public da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim str As String
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public ds1 As New DataSet
    Public ds2 As New DataSet
    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Dim er As Integer
    Private Sub insuranceform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        read = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source="
        datafile = "C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\HRIS SYSTEM\loginformdatabase\BLUESTREAM.accdb"
        connstring = read & datafile
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        ds.Clear()
        DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now
        DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now
        DateTimePicker3.Value = DateTime.Now
        If myconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            myconnection.Close()
        End If
        myconnection.Open()
        er = 0
        'cn.Open()
        str = "select * from insurancedetail"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "insurancedetail")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ds.Clear()
        str = "select * from insurancedetail"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "insurancedetail")
        If er = 0 Then
            Try
                cmd.Connection = myconnection
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into insurancedetail(Name,EmployeeID,PAN,UniversalAccountNumber,AdharNo,CurrentAddress,PermanentAddress,Landline,MartialStatus,MobileNumber,EmergencyContactNo,BloodGroup,DoyouHaveHDFCbankaccount,NameOfdependentmember_F) values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "')"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'if command is executed'
                Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("New insurance detail Added. Want To Add Another One.", "Added", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If result = DialogResult.No Then
                    Me.Close()
                ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    ds.Clear()
                    TextBox1.Clear()
                    TextBox2.Clear()
                    TextBox3.Clear()
                    TextBox4.Clear()
                    TextBox5.Clear()
                    TextBox6.Clear()
                    TextBox7.Clear()
                    TextBox8.Clear()
                    TextBox9.Clear()
                    TextBox10.Clear()
                    TextBox11.Clear()
                    TextBox12.Clear()
                    TextBox13.Clear()
                    TextBox14.Clear()
                    TextBox15.Clear()
                    TextBox16.Clear()
                    TextBox17.Clear()
                    TextBox18.Clear()
                    TextBox20.Clear()
                    ComboBox1.ResetText()
                    ComboBox2.ResetText()
                    ComboBox3.ResetText()
                    ComboBox4.ResetText()
                    ComboBox5.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker1.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker2.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker3.ResetText()
                    str = "select * from insurancedetail"
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(ds, "insurancedetail")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
            'insert close
        End If
        'myconnection close
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! What is your question exactly?

Comment: Learn how to use parameterized queries and passing values of the appropriate type to your database. The error will disappear. Now you are passing just a block of string data and hope that your database can sort this mess

Answer (score 0):

Way too many Class level variables. Especially not myconnection and cmd. What in the world is er? Procedures should not do too much. Move some code off to other procedures, especially if they will be called more than once.

For database objects use Using blocks. They will ensure that your objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. You don't appear to be using the DataAdapter so just fill a DataTable directly. It can be bound to a DataGridView.

There is no reason to fill the DataTable again before the save. You may want to refill is again after the save.

I am guessing at the datatypes in your database. You must check the database to get the correct datatypes and for string types get the size of the field. Convert your TextBox values to the correct types. I have only used a few of your fields for demonstration purposes. Make sure you add your parameters in the same order that they appear in the sql statement.

```
Private dt As New DataTable
Private connString As String = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\HRIS SYSTEM\loginformdatabase\BLUESTREAM.accdb"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SetDatePickerValues()
    FillDataTable()
End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into insurancedetail(Name,EmployeeID,PAN) Values(@Name, @EmployeeID, @PAN);", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PAN", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox3.Text
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
        FillDataTable()
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("New insurance detail Added. Want To Add Another One.", "Added", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Me.Close()
        Else
            ClearForm()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ClearForm()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    TextBox7.Clear()
    TextBox8.Clear()
    TextBox9.Clear()
    TextBox10.Clear()
    TextBox11.Clear()
    TextBox12.Clear()
    TextBox13.Clear()
    TextBox14.Clear()
    TextBox15.Clear()
    TextBox16.Clear()
    TextBox17.Clear()
    TextBox18.Clear()
    TextBox20.Clear()
    ComboBox1.ResetText()
    ComboBox2.ResetText()
    ComboBox3.ResetText()
    ComboBox4.ResetText()
    ComboBox5.ResetText()
    SetDatePickerValues()
End Sub

Private Sub FillDataTable()
    Try
        dt.Clear()
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From insurancedetail", cn)
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub SetDatePickerValues()
    DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now
    DateTimePicker3.Value = DateTime.Now
End Sub
```